# Equivalent group presentation

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

I have been trying to determine whether the following groups are isomorphic for a while now with no significant progress.

$G_1 = \langle x, y \mid xyx = yx^2y\rangle$

$G_2 = \langle x, y \mid xyx = yxy\rangle$

I would bet they are not, yet I cannot think of any characteristic that might set them apart. I know that the order of the groups must be the same and that the order of elements must match, but I cannot see how to use this here. In the comments it was suggested that I compute the abelianisations. However, the abelianisation of $G_1$ is $\langle x, y\mid 1=y\rangle$ and the abelianisation of $G_2$ is $\langle x, y\mid x=y\rangle$, which are both infinite cyclic. So abelianisations do not help either.

To show isomorphism I would have to show that there are elements in the other group that obey the same relation and which generate the entire group. I cannot see any obvious candidates.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, what tools do you have for determining if two groups are isomorphic or not? Did you try and of these, and if so why didn't they work?

Comment: Well to show they are isomorphic I would have to show that there are elements in the other group that obey the same relation and which generate the entire group. I cannot see any obvious candidates

Comment: To show that they are isomorphic you should be trying to use [Tietze transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations), as in fact what you say you'd need to prove here isn't quite correct (they need to satisfy that relation *and no more*!). However, you said that you think they are not isomorphic, so lets focus on that. The groups are infinite and have no non-trivial elements of finite order, so neither of these ideas will work. Have you come across the *abelianisation* of a group? Computing abelianisations is the obvious thing to do when given a group presentation.

Comment: Oh but does it work? On G_1 I am getting the relation y = 1 so the group is just generated by one element. On G_2 I am getting the relation x = y which once again seems to yield the group generated by one element

Comment: I have to confess that I cheated and used a computer. But  the groups are isomorphic, and the isomorphism is not too difficult.

Comment: @what I think it would be useful if you edited into the question your computation of the abelianisation (even just paraphrase your above comment) . Otherwise the question may get closed (it currently has 3/5 close votes).

Comment: As it has been a few days, I have edited @what's comments into the question to improve it, including their deleted comment about order of the group and orders of elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is in general a hard (infact, algorithmically undecidable!) problem to determine if two given finite group presentations define isomorphic groups. On the other hand, there are some obvious things to do before you need to start thinking hard.

1. Compute the abelianisations of each group. This will sometimes tell you that the groups are non-isomorphic.
2. Apply some simple [Tietze transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations) to one or both of the presentations, and check to see if the resulting presentations match. This will sometimes tell you that the groups are isomorphic.

Computing abelianisations doesn't work here - both groups have infinite cyclic abelinisations. So lets try Tietze transformations. Starting with $G_1$:
\begin{align*}
G_1
&\cong \langle x, y \mid xyx = yxy\rangle\\
&\cong \langle x, y, z \mid xyx = yxy, z=xy^{-1}\rangle&\text{add in new generator $z$ as $xy^{-1}$}\\
&\cong \langle x, y, z \mid zy^2zy = yzy^2, zy=x\rangle&\text{prepare to remove the generator $x$}\\
&\cong \langle y, z \mid zy^2z = yzy\rangle&\text{remove $x$ from presentation, tidy up}\\
&\cong\langle x, y \mid xyx = yx^2y\rangle\\
&\cong G_2
\end{align*}
Therefore, the groups are isomorphic.

---

The above working is formal and boring and not actually what I did. I actually added $z$ and removed $x$ in a single step as follows:
\begin{align*}
G_1
&\cong \langle x, y \mid xyx = yxy\rangle\\
&\cong \langle x, y \mid (xy)y(xy) = y(xy)y, z=xy^{-1}\rangle&x\mapsto xy\\
&\cong \langle x, y \mid xy^2x = yxy\rangle&\text{tidy up}\\
&\cong\langle x, y \mid xyx = yx^2y\rangle&x\leftrightarrow y\\
&\cong G_2
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to the "need to review the EoQS" meta post, club.  Really?

Comment: "I have tried blah (nothing concrete), but failed. I bet they are not, but I have absolutely no justification for saying that, but I thought it would trick users into thinking I actually gave a dang,  Please help" + PSQ = PSQ.

Comment: @amWhy The user interacted well in the comments. They gave concrete ideas on how to disprove isomorphism (although I've just spotted that they've since deleted that comment), and then correctly computed the abelianisation when I suggested they try that. Which is good enough for me :-)